# Xcode 4.1 Add and View TabBarController with existing ViewController

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

First of all sorry for my bad english and Im pretty new in these forums and Xcode programing.

So, Im writing an IPhone app with Xcode 4.1, that has Login and Register stuff visualized with UIViewController. When Im logged in, I need to visualize TabBar with different views.

I tried a lot of stuff and watched a lot of tutorials, all of them just start with the TabBarController, but I don't need it from the beginning, I just need to call it later.

The right way I believe should be just create new file .h, .m and .xib, then add the TabBarController and do a relation between TabBarController - view and File's Owner - view... but it don't let me do this thing. Obviously it don't visualize the right window.

How is the right way to do it?

Please help me, before my hair fall off...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `UITabBarController` as the root view controller, but display a modal registration / logon view controller over the top when the app begins.

Once the user has logged in, dismiss the modal view controller to reveal the tab bar controller below.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the answer.
About the modal view can you give me a sample code with this IF statement that is going to: - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions I guess... 
Thank you a lot again.

Answer (score 0):

You just use this code in your login button click or next viewcontroller viewwillappers method

UITabBarController *tabbar1 = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];

```
firstViewcontroller  *second = [[firstViewcontroller alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
second.title=@"";

SecondViewController *third=[[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
third.title=@"";

thirdViewController *one=[[thirdViewController alloc]initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
 one.title=@"";

tabbar1.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:one, second,third,nil]; 
tabbar1.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
[self.view addSubview:tabbar1.view];
```

I am sure it will work for you i always use this code for create tab bar in any view.